# Адаптивная верстка полноекранного окна ( вертикальные отступы у елементов )

Tags: вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, flexbox

Есть окно высотой в 100vh, внутри которого несколько елементов, потипу такого:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Решил для верстки использовать flexbox, использовал

```
justify-content: space-between;
```

И для вертикальных отступов блоков `padding`
Пример кода: https://codepen.io/Vdodovych/pen/aYbQrj

Недоволен тем, что при ресайзе окна, из-за этих `padding` мой контент "выезжает за рамки" блока с `height: 100vh`
Почему так происходит я понимаю (сумма height + margin + padding (для контента) > 100vh)

Вопрос: как избежать средствами **flexbox** или **grid** использованию таких отступов, реально ли ето, или необходимо просто `@media` и адаптивить ето (что довольно геморно).

Comment: Отступы появляются как минимум из-за того что у body есть марджины.

Comment: Етот пример "из вакуума", на проекте использую normaloze.css, да и я о том, что при указании padding елементы вылезают за пределы блока с 100vh.

Comment: ну очевидно что скролл появляется когда высота контента в хедре+контенте + футере + паддинги больше 100vh. а какое поведение Вы ожидаете? что отступы уменьшатся?

Comment: Суть вопроса: можно ли как-то средствами flexbox избежать етих padding, или "всё так и делают", а потом адаптивят контент, и сообственно, ети отступы с  @media ?

Comment: Тут больше вопрос о чистоте (правильности) кода (аля паттерне).

Comment: Короткий ответ - нет, флексбокс не сможет и 1+1+1 сделать 2.ну судя по Вашему макету логика размещения элементов такая: хедер всегда прибит к топу, контент всегда по центру, кнопка  - непонятно на каком то расстоянии от нижней точки страницы. для того что бы решить задачу определитесь какие высоты/отступы у вас хардовые/ а какие динамика. Судя по всему отступ снизу у блока с кнопкой, тогда было бы логично задать высоту блока в VH либо отступ снизу в Vh . но имейте введу что у Вас нету гарантии что высота контента не будет равно 100vh

Comment: По итогу, должно получиться: https://ibb.co/mAn3oS.

Comment: Можно поподробней о вышеизложеном вами, или хоть ссылочку где почитать.

Comment: P.S. Я всего-лиш учусь :)

Comment: Не надо примеров из вакуума и гадать, что у вас в коде. Просто [создайте MVCE](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Спасибо за совет, изменю топик в ближайшие пол часа.